# FlatFileItemReader cannot be cast when being accessed from custom ItemReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I currently have an application that I'm attempting to diagnose what in the setup I've done incorrectly, and am not having any luck in determining why it's not working outside of very specific situations.

First the code that I'm using.

**Configuration.java**

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.lcbo")
@EnableIntegration
public class COnfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private LCBOInventoryTrackerProperties inventoryTrackerProperties;

    @Bean
    public Job processLCBOInventory(@Qualifier("getLCBOStoreDataStep") final Step getLCBOStoreDataStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("processLCBOInventory")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(getLCBOStoreDataStep)
                .build();

    }

    /**
     * This tasklet downloads the .zip file, unzips, and saves it in the appropriate folder under resources.
     * Execute at 6am daily
     *
     //     * @param AcquireDataFileTasklet acquireDataFiles
     * @return Step - returns Step status; either SUCCESS or FAILURE
     */

    @Bean
    public Step getCurrentLCBODataStep(final AcquireDataFileTasklet acquireDataFiles,
                                       final ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener) {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("getCurrentLCBODataStep")
                .tasklet(acquireDataFiles)
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .listener(listener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step getLCBOStoreDataStep(final LCBOStoreReader lcboStoreReader,
                                     final LCBOStoreWriter lcboStoreWriter) {

        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("getLCBOStoreDataStep")
                .<LCBOStore, LCBOStore>chunk(inventoryTrackerProperties.getDefaults().getChunkSize())
                .reader(lcboStoreReader)
                .writer(lcboStoreWriter)
                .build();
    }
}
```

The reader class

```
@Component
public class LCBOStoreReader extends AbstractLCBOReader implements ItemReader, InterstepDataRetriever {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LCBOStoreReader.class);

    @Override
    public ItemReader<LCBOStore> read() throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        Class<LCBOStore> classType = LCBOStore.class;

        return createCSVReader(classType, currentCSVFilePath, inventoryTrackerProperties.getLCBOFilPropertiess().getStores());
    }
/*
    @Override
    public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
        this.currentWorkingDate = (String) jobContext.get("currentWorkingDateKey");
    }
*/
    @Override
    public void retrieveInterstepDataFromJobContext(final ExecutionContext jobContext) {
        this.currentCSVFilePath = (String) jobContext.get("currentCSVFilePathKey");
    }
}
```

and the class it extends (because the FlatFileItemReader setup is used by multiple readers)

```
public abstract class AbstractLCBOReader {

    @Autowired
    protected LCBOInventoryTrackerProperties inventoryTrackerProperties;

    protected String currentCSVFilePathKey;
    protected String currentCSVFilePath;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractLCBOReader.class);

    protected <T> ItemReader<T> createCSVReader(final Class<T> classType,
                                                 final String currentCSVFilePath,
                                                 final LCBOFileDetailsProperties properties) {

        FlatFileItemReader<T> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        // Skip a line to ignore the header information in these files
        reader.setLinesToSkip(properties.getNumberOfLinesToSkipInFile());
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(currentCSVFilePath + File.separator + properties.getFileName()));
        reader.setLineMapper(createLineMapper(classType, properties));
        reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy());
        reader.setEncoding("utf8");

        return reader;
    }

    private <T> LineMapper<T> createLineMapper(final Class<T> classType, final LCBOFileProperties.LCBOFileDetailsProperties properties) {
        DefaultLineMapper<T> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(createLineTokenizer(properties));
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(createFieldSetMapper(classType));

        return lineMapper;
    }

    private <T> FieldSetMapper<T> createFieldSetMapper(final Class<T> classType) {
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<T> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(classType);

        return fieldSetMapper;
    }

    private LineTokenizer createLineTokenizer(final LCBOFileProperties.LCBOFileDetailsProperties properties) {
        LCBOFileProperties.Column[] columns = properties.getColumns();
        int[] columnIndexes = new int[columns.length];
        String[] columnNames = new String[columns.length];

        // populating the columnIndexes
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            columnIndexes[i] = columns[i].getColumnIndex();
            columnNames[i] = columns[i].getColumnName();
        }

        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(columnIndexes);
        lineTokenizer.setNames(columnNames);
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setQuoteCharacter('"');

        return lineTokenizer;
    }
}
```

The error when executing this will be that the object cannot be cast from FlatFileItemreader to the object passed as the first parameter in createCSVReader. Here's an example.

```
public class LCBOStore {

    private Long id;
    private String addressLineOne;
    private String addressLineTwo;
    private String city;
    private String postalCode;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String updatedAt; //Convert to Date

    public LCBOStore(final Long id, final String addressLineOne, final String addressLineTwo, final String city,
                     final String postalCode, final String latitude, final String longitude, final String updatedAt) {
        this.id = id;
        this.addressLineOne = addressLineOne;
        this.addressLineTwo = addressLineTwo;
        this.city = city;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getAddressLineOne() {
        return addressLineOne;
    }

    public String getAddressLineTwo() {
        return addressLineTwo;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setAddressLineOne(final String addressLineOne) {
        this.addressLineOne = addressLineOne;
    }

    public void setAddressLineTwo(final String addressLineTwo) {
        this.addressLineTwo = addressLineTwo;
    }

    public void setCity(final String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(final String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public void setLatitude(final String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(final String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(final String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StoreDBModel [id=" + id + ", addressLineOne=" + addressLineOne + ", city=" + city 
                + ", postalCode=" + postalCode + ", latitude=" + latitude + ", longitude="
                + longitude + ", updatedAt=" + updatedAt + "]";
    }
}
```

Now if I move the FlatFileItemReader mode that exists in createCSVReader into the constructor of the custom Reader class, or have it so it's in the configuration file, it works fine. However, I couldn't figure out how to work with job and step context in those configurations (the constructor executes before you can access step and jobContext it seems from my testing, and I could never figure how to access when put in the Config class.). Plus to me at least, it looks cleaner to have the Reader code in it's own file not being stuffed in the constructor.

So in a nutshell, is there a way to fix this os that having it in it's own reader class would work? Am I doing this incorrectly and using bad practices? Maybe a mix of the two? If there's anything missing please ask away and I'll attempt to clarify.

Comment: Your reader return `ItemReader<YourObject>` where as it should call the read method on the delegating item reader and return `YourObject`. The whole purpose of the read method is to return actual object NOT the underlying item reader.

Comment: `LCBOStoreReader.read()` may return `LCBOStore`, and not `ItemReader`...

Comment: Knew it would be something simple, the read functions were working as intended, just for the root csvParser class, there's wasn't an auto way to call read. Either way, thanks for the heads up, it helped to get me a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer to be very simple with some help from those in the comments. Here's my solution.

First, add the bolded code to the abstract class createCSVWriter method

```
**protected <T> T** createCSVReader(final Class<T> classType,
                                final String currentCSVFilePath,
                                final LCBOFileDetailsProperties properties) throws Exception {

    FlatFileItemReader<T> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    // Skip a line to ignore the header information in these files
    reader.setLinesToSkip(properties.getNumberOfLinesToSkipInFile());
    reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(currentCSVFilePath + File.separator + properties.getFileName()));
    reader.setLineMapper(createLineMapper(classType, properties));
    reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy());
    reader.setEncoding("utf8");

    **return reader.read();**
}
```

Doing the read call manually will prevent it returning more then needed for your reader class. Then in the reader class edit the following

```
@Override
public **LCBOStore** read() throws **Exception**, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    Class<LCBOStore> classType = LCBOStore.class;

    return createCSVReader(classType, currentCSVFilePath, inventoryTrackerProperties.getLCBOFilPropertiess().getStores());
}
```

This just returns the object you've created and hence issue resolved.